# Installed Ubuntu alongside Gentoo, now I can't boot

Tags: grub2, partitioning, 18.04

I am having some trouble partitioning. I'll try to explain everything from the beginning. I have two laptops, 1 and 2.
On laptop 1 I have only Ubuntu 18.04 installed, and I made a backup of my system by following the instructions [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087). On laptop 2 I installed Gentoo on `dev/sda`, following a tutorial on Youtube. The partitions `dev/sdaX` for X=1,2,3,4 are `boot`,`grub`,`swap`,`root`, respectively. The Gentoo installation completed successfully - it would boot up to a CLI fine and I could move around and edit files.

I tried to do the following: Install Ubuntu alongside Gentoo on laptop 2, and restore the copy of laptop 1 onto this partition. First, I had to resize some partitions. In the Gentoo install, I made `sda4` take up the remainder of the drive. On the Ubuntu live disk I ran Gparted and resized `sda4` to take up around 20 GiB, and made the remainder of the drive (partition `sda5`) available for Ubuntu.

During the Ubuntu installation I chose "install Ubuntu alongside Gentoo", and divided it to save around 20 GiB and leave the rest for Ubuntu. I misunderstood this part - the net consequence was that `sda5` was resized to 20 GiB, and the remainder of the drive (`sda6`) contained Ubuntu. The rest of the installation was successful, and I restored my backup from laptop 1. It seems like it completed successfully, because I can mount `sda6` and all the right files are there. Importantly: at this step I had booted from grub into the new Ubuntu install, and Gentoo was still available from the menu.

I tried to reboot, and got a GRUB menu that only had Ubuntu in it. Confusing, but ok. I tried to boot into Ubuntu and got the following errors:

```
error: no such device XXXXXX
error: no such partition
error: you need to install the kernel first
```

I ran the `boot-repair` script and it said it failed; 
I got the following pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nJ3r2dZ5sy/

Restarting, my boot menu now has Ubuntu and Gentoo available. I have tried to boot into Gentoo and got in just fine. I tried to boot into Ubuntu and the power up dots are lit, but it seems to hang there. If I tap the power button then it shuts down in a safe-looking way, but it doesn't get to the login screen or anything.

If it's possible to tell, did I do anything wrong? If so, what, and how do I fix it/avoid it in future? I still have my backup so reinstalling ubuntu on `sda6` or whatever and restoring again is an option. But I'd like to understand it a bit better.

Comment: Very happy to provide diagnostics if people tell me what to run - I'm not sure what is helpful to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booting into Ubuntu would not work, but I could boot into recovery mode. From there, running `fsck` gave me an error like `Could not find partition XXXX`, which fits with the message I was getting before.

It turns out that every partition has a so-called `UUID`, which is stored in the `/etc/fstab` file. When I changed my partitions, the `UUID` for my root partition did not match the one in `/etc/fstab`. To find out the correct one, I did

`blkid /dev/sda6`

in the root command shell in recovery mode, which gave me a different id, call it `YYYY`. Now, the problem was solved by opening the `/etc/fstab` file (which was initially read-only, even as root, but the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383595/repairing-fstab-read-only) resolved that problem) and changing the UUID there to the correct value. I copied the line that was above it apart from that.

And now I can boot into Ubuntu!